# Gstreamer debug pipeline c++

Tags: c++, debugging, gstreamer, pipeline

I am trying to transcode a gstreamer bash script to c++ code, y but I am not able to save de debuggin log into a file

This is my code

```js
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      YoctoLinuxSystem* hola;
      //hola->YoctoLinuxSystem();



   CustomData DataTest, DataDvi;
   GstBus *bus;
   GstMessage *msg;
   GstStateChangeReturn ret;
   GMainLoop *loop; 
   


   //vector<string> lines = YoctoLinuxSystem::getCmdOutputAsLines("./scripts/get_system_temps.sh");
   

     gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
  
  /******************************/
  /****AJUSTES GSTREAMER TEST****/
  /******************************/

  DataTest.source = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "source");
  DataTest.capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter","caps");
  DataTest.sink = gst_element_factory_make ("imxipuvideosink", "sink");
  

  DataTest.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline"); 
  
    if (!DataTest.pipeline || !DataTest.source || !DataTest.capsfilter || !DataTest.sink) {
     g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
     return -1;
   }  

   /* Modify the source's properties */
   g_object_set (DataTest.source, "pattern", 0, NULL);
   g_object_set(DataTest.capsfilter, "caps", gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 25, 1,"width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920, "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080, "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB", NULL), NULL);
   

   /* Build the pipeline */
   gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (DataTest.pipeline), DataTest.source, DataTest.capsfilter, DataTest.sink, NULL);

   if (gst_element_link (DataTest.source, DataTest.capsfilter) != TRUE) {
     g_printerr ("Elements source-caps could not be linked.\n");
     gst_object_unref (DataTest.pipeline);
     return -1;
   }

   if (gst_element_link (DataTest.capsfilter, DataTest.sink) != TRUE) {
     g_printerr ("Elements caps-sink could not be linked.\n");
     gst_object_unref (DataTest.pipeline);
     return -1;
   }

    gst_element_link_many (DataTest.source, DataTest.capsfilter, DataTest.sink, NULL);
    
    
    /******************************/
    /****AJUSTES GSTREAMER DVI****/
    /******************************/
    DataDvi.source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
    DataDvi.sink = gst_element_factory_make ("imxipuvideosink", "sink");
      

    DataDvi.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline"); 
      
    if (!DataDvi.pipeline || !DataDvi.source || !DataDvi.sink) {
         g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
         return -1;
    }  

       /* Modify the source's properties */
    g_object_set (DataDvi.source, "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);
           

       /* Build the pipeline */
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (DataDvi.pipeline), DataDvi.source, DataDvi.sink, NULL);

    
    if (gst_element_link (DataDvi.source, DataDvi.sink) != TRUE) {
         g_printerr ("Elements caps-sink could not be linked.\n");
         gst_object_unref (DataDvi.pipeline);
         return -1;
    }

    gst_element_link_many (DataDvi.source, DataDvi.sink, NULL);
        
        
    GST_DEBUG=2;
        
    ifstream fileread;
   // fileread.open("/var/log/data.log");
    
  while(1)
  {     
   ifstream fileread("/var/log/data.log");
  
   if (!fileread.good())
   {
    /* Start playing */
    //g_print ("Now playing: \n");
    gst_element_set_state (DataDvi.pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
    ret = gst_element_set_state (DataTest.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
   g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
   gst_object_unref (DataTest.pipeline);
   return -1;
    }
   }
   
   else
   {
    gst_element_set_state (DataTest.pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
    ret = gst_element_set_state (DataDvi.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
           
           /*HERE I NEED TO KNOW THE DEBUG OF THE PIPELINE*/
           
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
     g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
     gst_object_unref (DataDvi.pipeline);
     return -1;
    }
   }
  }
  
    g_print ("SALE\n");
  return 0;
 }
```

I am using gstreamer-1.0 library and I have seen that I need use GST_DEBUG_FILE but I do not know how call these functions from c++.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

There is a rich API behind the debugging and logging infrastructure.  Take a look at [this documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstInfo.html).

For example, you might set some default values when the environment variables have not been setup.

```
if (!gst_debug_is_active()) {
    gst_debug_set_active(TRUE);
    GstDebugLevel dbglevel = gst_debug_get_default_threshold();
    if (dbglevel < GST_LEVEL_ERROR) {
        dbglevel = GST_LEVEL_ERROR;
        gst_debug_set_default_threshold(dbglevel);
    }
}
```

For that, the previous poster correctly advised you about the environment variable, GST_DEBUG_FILE.  You could do putenv() before gst_init().

If you want to get fancy, you could can replace the default log function, `gst_debug_log_default()`.  You do this by adding your own via, `gst_debug_add_log_function()`; then remove the default, `gst_debug_remove_log_function(gst_debug_log_default)`.  If you simply wish to change the file, then `gst_debug_add_log_function (gst_debug_log_default, log_file, NULL)`, for some open and ready `FILE* log_file`.

Answer (score 1):

GST_DEBUG_FILE is environment variable, so it has nothing to do with C++.

You could just use something like

```
export GST_DEBUG_FILE=~/gst.log
```

before run your application. Or add something like this to your bash startup script.